# Docker images migration approach (Nexus from azure registry)

Tags: azure, containers, nexus3, azure-container-registry

Is there any way to moving bulk docker images from nexus registry to azure container registry.

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Azure CLI [`az acr import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az_acr_import) to import the images from the nexus registry to Azure Container Registry. If the nexus registry is a private registry, you need to add the parameters `--username` and `--password` as the credential of the nexus registry.